# What's this variable in a Unity C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm studying it by reading the scripts that comes with the assets I downloaded from the Unity Asset Store. That's just how I learn new stuff so forgive me if this is something that should be readily obvious to someone who read through a standard Unity coding tutorial.

The code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D
{

    public class PlatformerCharacter2D : MonoBehaviour
    {

        // some variable declarations here

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            m_Grounded = false;
            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
            for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                    m_Grounded = true;
            }
            m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", m_Grounded);
            m_Anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        }

        // some function declarations here

    }
}
```

What's the `gameObject` variable to the right of the `colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject` statement?

It's not defined anywhere. I looked at the other C# files in the script folder, all of which are in `namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D`, and the variable `gameObject` isn't defined in any of them. Is it a variable within the `System` or `UnityEngine` namespace?

I used the Go To Definition in Visual Studio and it pops up a dialog saying "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret".

Comment: How about looking into the [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gameObject` variable is defined in `Component` class which is inherited by `MonoBehaviour`, which Every Unity objects should inherit. It points the very `GameObject` instance which should exist in `Scene`. If you don't understand what I've just said, then I strongly suggest you to study from official Unity tutorial, NOT from just reading existing code. These are the basics of Unity programming, so not knowing this would make you feel your studying very hard.

Comment: Then when you understand it and write a whole game using MonoBehaviour, you'll have the fun of learning how to write everything the new way in ECS and dots

Comment: Thanks. Yup, I just decided that's what I should do. I'm just finding it hard to search for a Unity coding tutorial. Most tutorials I see online has that "without coding" feature. Which is too bad, I would really like to approach their tutorial project through coding.

Comment: "Without Coding" is absolutely not a bad thing!! Before start coding, you have to know about what is `Unity3D`. Here's official unity tutorial page: https://learn.unity.com/

Comment: That's where I started actually. I completed that whole "Start with your first project" section but what I did wrong was not going back to that page after completing that section. Instead I wandered off elsewhere, reading tutorial blogs and whatnot. My bad. The "Explore Unity skills & features" section is where I should be now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's define in Component class , and monobehavior inherit it.
and you `using UnityEngine;` so you can found it.

```
public class MonoBehaviour : Behaviour { //...}
public class Behaviour : Component {//...}

namespace UnityEngine
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Base class for everything attached to GameObjects.
    [NativeClass("Unity::Component")]
    [NativeHeader("Runtime/Export/Component.bindings.h")]
    [RequiredByNativeCode]
    public class Component : Object
    {
        public Component();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     The game object this component is attached to. A component is always attached
        //     to a game object.
        public GameObject gameObject { get; }
    }

//...
}
```